# include any plugin within other plugin or use other plugin within other

Tags: plugins

I want to do something like: want to display one plugin's page on other plugin's page.

I have read [Including file or library from other plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97234/including-file-or-library-from-other-plugin) 
but its not working for me or either am doing something wrong

let say I want to use plugin-1 into plugin-2

here whats the meaning of

```
do_action( 'my_library_loaded', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );
```

plugin_dir_path( **FILE** ) path of which plugin (plugin-1 or plugin-2 ?) and where I have to put this? (in plugin-1 or plugin-2 ?)

same question for `add_action( 'my_library_loaded', 'other_plugin_init_handler' );`

any suggestion please

Comment: If your having a problem with the answer on that question your better off commenting on it then making a duplicate question. Also could do with a little more info than its not working.

Comment: My suggestion is to add your code to the question. :)

Comment: I have updated but how to link my question with other question in stackexchange

Answer (score 1):

1. The first plugin, the base, calls `do_action()` or `apply_filters()`.
2. The second plugin, the one relying on the the first, uses `add_action()` or `add_filter()`.

### Basic example

#### Base plugin

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: Base
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/112075
 */

class Plugin_Base {

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'wp_loaded', array ( $this, 'plugin_setup' ) );
    }

    public function plugin_setup()
    {
        $headers = get_file_data(
            __FILE__,
            array(
                'name' => 'Plugin Name',
                'uri'  => 'Plugin URI'
            )
        );
        $data    = new stdClass;
        $data->plugin_name = $headers[ 'name' ];
        $data->plugin_uri  = $headers[ 'uri' ];
        $data->plugin_file = __FILE__;

        do_action( 'plugin_base_loaded', $data );
    }
}

new Plugin_Base;
```

Note the custom action `plugin_base_loaded`. This will be the anchor for all depending plugins.

Now let’s create a second plugin that should run after the base has been loaded.

#### Addon plugin

```
<?php # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
/**
 * Plugin Name: Base Addon
 */
class Plugin_Base_Addon {

    protected $data;

    public function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'plugin_base_loaded', array ( $this, 'setup' ) );
    }

    public function setup( $data )
    {
        $this->data = $data;

        add_action( 'wp_footer', array( $this, 'wp_footer' ) );
    }

    public function wp_footer()
    {
        printf(
            '<p>I am an addon for <a href="%1$s">%2$s</a> which lives in <code>%3$s</code>.</p>',
            esc_url( $this->data->plugin_uri ),
            esc_html( $this->data->plugin_name ),
            esc_html( $this->data->plugin_file )
        );
    }
}

new Plugin_Base_Addon;
```

This second plugin will not do anything if the base is not active. And if it *is* active, it will wait until the base has been loaded. Then it will print information about the base into the front-end footer.

You can see a broader example in my article [Initialize a plugin with a configuration object](http://wpkrauts.com/2013/initialize-a-plugin-with-a-configuration-object/), code examples, including an additional plugin, are [on GiHub](https://github.com/wpkrauts/blogposts).